# Moving prestashop to a new domain/server

Tags: prestashop

I am moving a prestashop project to a new server and new domain.

I have moved database (mysql) and www files (including .htaccess).

I have changed database credentials and host in config/settings.inc.php

When i am trying to open the new domain in my browser,i have a redirection to old domain...

I think i have to change domain somewhere in config file.

I have search with grep, i have search in database, in .htaccess and i do not found anything.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

enters the backend and go to "Preferences" and then "url and seo". Towards the end of the page you will find text input where to put the data in the domain. Upgrade those and you've solved.

Comment: I have this error: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load template file 'controllers/modules/login_addons.tpl''. I think i have to change the url by myself in database first but i do not know where...

Comment: when it appears that the error domain is correct? checks that the permissions are correct files must be 755

Comment: I have set permissions. The file does not exist in the project

Comment: You excuse me, that file should not be you. you have special Moduels or override?

Comment: I don't Know, this is not my project in fact. But if thaïs file is referenced it should exist...

Answer (score 0):

Dump your database into file, in this file search and replace old domain by new domain.

The domain is saved under ps_configuration two times, but cms pages or stats need to have the new domain too, soo easiest to replace in all database.